# How I logged out of Facebook from website but my Facebook account on Facebook page still login?

Tags: php, facebook, logout

I use Login Facebook SDK PHP. Everything works well. But now I get trouble with `getLogoutUrl`. When I logout of my website, my Facebook account on Facebook is being logged out too.

That means after I logout Facebook from my website, if I login again on my website the login screen with my email and password is appear instead of a normal screen as I expect.

```
self::$logoutUrl = self::$helper->getLogoutUrl(self::$session, 'http://'.$serverName.'/customer/logout/' );
```

How I still not log out of Facebook when I logout Facebook from my website?

Answer (score 0):

First please clear your logic..

1) You are using your facebook acount to login to your website, then it means if a user have a F.B account then it login.
2) if you are facebook to login then it is ofcurse that when you logout from your website then you will also from facebook...

Comment: Thanks your comment, but, i find that if we use login facebook Javascript SDK, when we logout of a website, it just logout at this website, our account on Facebook page still login. I wanna make like this

Answer (score -1):

Logging out from Facebook connect website effectively logs you out of Facebook as well.

Comment: It doesn't *have* to work that way.